# HTTP PUT Method not allowed with curl (no PHP or CGI)

Tags: apache, http, put

I have a newly installed Apache HTTP server over centos machine. I am trying to upload a file with the HTTP PUT method via curl command. Unfortunately, I am facing 405 Method Not allowed error.

I am not using any PHP or CGI here. Can someone please help me here?

---

Example:

#### PUT Request:

curl localhost:80 --upload-file text.txt

#### HTTP Response:

Method Not Allowed

The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /text.txt.

---

Regards,

Ankit

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of PHP, CGI or similar, you won't be able to use HTTP PUT on a stock Apache.

If you'd like to use PHP, here is a very basic example from the PHP Manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php

Note: This is very insecure to allow an HTTP PUT openly in this way. You should apply authentication and authorization access controls if you intend to deploy this beyond your local development environment.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for the information. I have created a put.php script and placed it under /var/www directly. Also i have updated by httpd.conf file with "Script PUT /put.php" line followed by service restart. The issue is still the same. Sorry i am new to http server.

Comment: You likely need to install or enable mod_php